# Simple sortable list with rails and a :pos column inside a table?

Tags: list, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-sortable

Im looking for a simple sortable list solution or method to update the position of max 50 rows. I tried several gems but they all store the id as a big value ( like reorder) or in a seperate table.

What would be a solution to update a table with questions where id => x and update the pos column also taking into consideration multiple users at the same time. Or is there a gem for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but would it be possible to have another column on your table and update that column when you want to reorder?